# Changing dataframe format and performing ANOVA with replicates as columns

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data frame that looks like this, and would like to do multiple comparisons between treatment groups (vehicle vs drugA, vehicle vs. drugB, drugA vs. drugB). Would ANOVA be suitable in this case?

```
        Vehicle    Vehicle    Drug_A    Drug_A    Drug_B    Drug_B   
Gene1    4.209      8.11      4.209      8.11     4.209      8.11
Gene2    8.395      5.83      3.295      2.51     49.25      45.2
Gene3    30.4       44.3      7.20       48.2     42.1       4.1
```

I tried to do multiple t tests but can't seem to get the data frame in the right orientation, and unable to group the data properly. What would be the best way of going about this? Sorry, I am new to R!

Comment: what  do your two `Vehicle` columns represent? (something like `reshape2::melt` followed by `lm` followed by use of the `emmeans` package should do what you want ...)

Comment: They are two technical replicates. I've tried melt but not quite getting the result that I want!

Comment: does the first `Vehicle` column correspond to the first `Drug_A` and the the first `Drug_B` column?